# Asp .Net MVC, how to put/include values to DropDownListFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/dropdownlist-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3razor/) which works very fine. But the problem is that it only provides `key` and without it own `value` (As shown in the picture below). How to include values to each of these keys?

**Inspected Elements** (Picture)

[image]

**Model**

```
[Required( ErrorMessage = "Selection is a MUST" )]
public string SelectedItem { get; set; }

private List<string> _items;
public List<string> Items 
{
    get
    {
        _items = new List<string>();
        _items.Add("One");
        _items.Add("Two");
        _items.Add("Three");
        return _items;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //Render Action
    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        DropdownListModel model = new DropdownListModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    //Process Action
    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult Index(DropdownListModel model)
    {
        //TODO: Validate using if(ModelState.IsValid) and process information
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<div>
    <!--Render the DropDownListmodel -->
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {           
        <p>@Html.ValidationSummary()</p>
        <p>Select an Item : @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItem, new SelectList(Model.Items), "--Choose any Item--" )</p>   
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />         
    }

    <!-- Display Selected Item -->
     @if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.SelectedItem))
     {
          <span>Selected Item : @Model.SelectedItem</span>
     }

</div>
```

**What I Attempted**

I replaced the codes in models with the code below. But I have error saying `Models.KeyValueModel: : EntityType 'KeyValueModel' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
KeyValueModels: EntityType: EntitySet 'KeyValueModels' is based on type 'KeyValueModel' that has no keys defined.`

```
public List<KeyValueModel> Items
{
    get
    {
        List<KeyValueModel> item = new List<KeyValueModel>();
        var n = new KeyValueModel();
        n.Key = "1";
        n.Value = "One";
        item.Add(n);

        n = new KeyValueModel();
        n.Key = "2";
        n.Value = "Second";
        item.Add(n);

        n = new KeyValueModel();
        n.Key = "3";
        n.Value = "Three";
        item.Add(n);
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just create a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (that is what the 2nd parameter of `DropDownListFor()` expects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify on your HttpGet request your Key Value pair like this one:

```
DropdownListModel model = new DropdownListModel();
model.ItemList = new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "One", Value = "1" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Two", Value = "2" }
        };
```

Then on your model, add this:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ItemList { get; set; }
```

And on your View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItem, Model.Items, "--Choose any Item--" )
```

Comment: Using `new SelectList()` to create another identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the first one is pointless extra overhead

Comment: I am open to suggestions, what should it be? I didn't get it actually :)

Comment: `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> { get; set; }` and `model.ItemList = new List<SelectListItem>(){ ....};` and `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItem, Model.ItemList, .... )`

Comment: Okay, thanks @StephenMuecke, new learning for today, edited as suggested by you :)

Answer (score 0):

add the Model as:

```
     public string nameofdropdown{ get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listyouwanttodisplay{ get; set; }
```

In get method:

```
       Model model=new Model;
       List<SelectListItem> cd = Get() //call here----

        var additionaldata= new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = null,
            Text = "--- place holder---"
        };
        cd.Insert(0, additionaldata);
        model.listyouwanttodisplay=cd;            
        return View (model);
```

In View:

```
     <div>
       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.nameofdropdown, new 
       SelectList(Model.listyouwanttodisplay, "Value","Text"),htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
```